# Port forwarding to the internal IP?

Tags: c#, networking, dns, ip, portforwarding

My customer has VM with public IP and the environment will be like as below,

We can able to access the public IP from outside, but it cannot be accessible from inside the VM.

So what will happen, while deploying our own web application into the IIS of customer's VM, it can be accessible from outside, but we have done some internal communications from the server side to access the API's which is deployed as sub-application.

It cannot be done due to the server cannot resolve the public IP inside the VM.

I have following queries,

1. Do I want to do any code changes from my web application?
2. Otherwise is there any option like port forwarding to achieve my solution.

Help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: thats a very open ended question - and not really a stack overflow thing.  Your app only needs to know of the local IP, the firewall/router will handle the outside..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @BugFinder I think you can't understand the environment which i have explained above, it might become comes under development also. We can able to get the remote address as well as host details while accessing the API sub-application. It might depend on the environment which the application going to be deployment.

Comment: Actually I do understand, Ive done a lot of firewalls, routers, and web stuff.. you havent explained your issue ... the external IP is not essential to your app

Comment: How could you say that external ip is not essential? While accessing globally the external IP is important.

Comment: So what does your app need to know its external IP for?